# SQL query for ranking with ties

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a **Book(id,name,weight)** table 
I have to produce an output which has two columns **(rank, weight)** 
ties are given same rank. For example if there are three books with weight 10,10,11
then output will be 
**1 10

1 10

2 11**

I am not sure how to begin with this. Any hints/pointers

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely what the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `dense_rank()` does:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by weight), weight
from book
order by 1
```

The difference to the `rank()` function is, that after a duplicate rank, `dense_rank()` has no gaps. `rank()` would yield 1,1,3 for the sample data.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c36837883f77b573dc4db2ccb8b92b2d)

Answer (score 0):

With dense_rank() window function you can get that easily:

```
select dense_rank()over(order by weight) rank,weight from book
```

Schema:

> ```
> create table book(id int ,name varchar(50),weight int);
> insert into book values(1,'Book A',10);
> insert into book values(2,'Book B',11);
> insert into book values(3,'Book C',10);
> ```

Query:

> ```
> select dense_rank()over(order by weight) rank,weight from book
> ```

Output:

> | rank | weight |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 10 |
> | 1 | 10 |
> | 2 | 11 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c735bf8afb443f82e09e3968dd9c24ae)*